# AppStore dashboard when clicking Submit for review

Tags: ios

After clicking the `Submit for review` button in `https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps` I get the following message. Even though there is nothing wrong with the form. Everything is filled out. This is an update to an existing application that is live. Any idea on why this is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Copyright text field]

You must fill the "Copyright" with the name of the person or entity that owns the rights of app

Comment: No way ... It must have a bug ... I thought it was optional since it didn't have any indication of an error. That was it. Thank you!

Comment: No it is not a bug the same error was happened when I was submitting tenth updation of my app for review.